# AutoCheck CheckBox

Tags: javascript, css

Is there anyone who know how to AutoCheck, CheckBox in the code below either via css or Java - with the option to uncheck by clicking

```
<span id="ctl00_bc_custom_element_43" class="checkbox">
<input id="#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$bc$custom_element_43$0">
<label for="ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0">Yes, sign me up!</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you say more about what exactly you mean by "auto check"?  When do you want the checkbox to be checked?  Page load time? Some other time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_bc_custom_element_43").checked = true
```

Comment: Hey, I can not get it to work, this is the correct way to insert it on? <script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementByID('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0').checked = true; </script>

Comment: Still dont work, can you make an excample where i can se it works?

Answer (score 3):

You mean by giving the `<input>` element the "checked" attribute?

```
<input checked='true' id="#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$bc$custom_element_43$0">
```

Comment: That " after the id should be a ', though (or the one before the id should be a ")

Comment: Like this? <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementByID('a#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0').checked = true;
</script>

Comment: @Zak thanks - for some reason Chrome is just a real pain with the cut and the paste :-)

Comment: @Pete the parameter to "getElementById()" should be the exact string used for the "id" parameter.

Comment: Still dont work, can you make an excample where i can se it works?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$bc$custom_element_43$0" checked="checked">
```

or in JS

```
document.getElementByID('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0').checked = true;
```

Comment: Hey, I can not get it to work, this is the correct way to insert it on? <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementByID('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0').checked = true;
</script>

Comment: That's correct, but you must add that script after the input declaration or wait for the document to load.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_43_0').checked = true;
```

Change ByID to ById.